# Unable to retrieve name of dataframes using for loop in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, names

I want to upload 2 dataframes(test1,test2) in ADLS Gen2 directory but unable to retrieve the names of the dataframes.

Traditionally when I upload 1 dataframe(df) I pass the name of the dataframe directly into the function as shown below.

```
upload_df_to_adls_path(
    df,
    adls_dirname=staging_dirname,
    adls_filename=staging_filename,
    container_name=staging_container_name,
    storage_account_name=staging_account_name,
    storage_account_key=staging_account_key,
    )

def upload_df_to_adls_path(
   df: pd.DataFrame, 
   adls_dirname: str,
   adls_filename: str,
   container_name: str,
   storage_account_name: str, 
   storage_account_key: str,
 ):
```

"""
Upload a pandas dataframe to the specified ADLS path as a single JSON lines files
"""
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True,
date_format='iso')

```
  adls_service_client = get_adls_client(storage_account_name, 
  storage_account_key)
  file_system_client =
```

adls_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=container_name)

```
try:
    file_system_client.create_directory(adls_dirname)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(adls_dirname)
    file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(adls_filename)
    file_client.upload_data(json_data, overwrite=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But since I need to write 2 dataframes I am using for loop

Getting error when trying to print the names of the dataframes

```
final_df=[test1.json,test2.json]       
for files in final_df:
  print(files.name)
#     upload_df_to_adls_path(files,adls_dirname="FinalFilesToUse",adls_filename=files,
#         container_name=staging_container_name,
#           storage_account_name=staging_account_name,
#               storage_account_key=staging_account_key)       

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: `Series` have a `name` attribute, but `DataFrame` does not. What information are you trying to pull?

Comment: The names of the dataframes to be able to upload them in the data lake

Comment: As in the variable you assigned to them? It's unclear what you mean by the "name" of the dataframe.

Comment: I have updated my question to show what i usually do when uploading 1 dataframe while this time I need to upload multiple dataframes in the same location so trying to make use of the loop

Comment: When you say "pass the name of the dataframe directly", are you referring to the `df` argument in `upload_df_to_adls_path`? So far, I only see that you pass the DataFrame itself, but without the code of the function, I can't see where you are pulling this "name" from the dataframe. Are you referring to the `staging_filename`?

Comment: edited the code further

Comment: The only thing I see you doing with the DataFrame is converting it to JSON. At no point, do I see you pulling a "name" from it. You still need to clarify what you mean by the "name" of the DataFrame.

Comment: What I mean is I should be able to pass the dataframes test1 & test2 into this function "upload_df_to_adls_path" which is not happening at this point.

Comment: You can pass `file` as the argument to `df` but not to `adls_filename`. You need a proper string not a reference to the DataFrame.

Comment: Exactly that is my question as in how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to pull the variable name and use it as a string for the `adls_filename`. However, if you're just going to name them "test1", "test2", etc.. then...

```
final_df=[test1,test2]       
for i,files in enumerate(final_df):
    file_name = f'test{i+1}'
    upload_df_to_adls_path(files,adls_dirname="FinalFilesToUse",adls_filename=file_name,
         container_name=staging_container_name,
         storage_account_name=staging_account_name,
         storage_account_key=staging_account_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better workaround this problem

```
final_df=["test1.json","test2.json"]       
for files in final_df:
upload_df_to_adls_path(eval(files.replace('"', '').replace('.json', ''))
        ,adls_dirname="FinalFilesToUse",adls_filename=f"{files}",
      container_name=staging_container_name,
         storage_account_name=staging_account_name,
                 storage_account_key=staging_account_key)
```